# How do I access data from Google My Maps in my application?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Disclaimer: I am just getting started with Google (My) Maps and I feel like I must really be missing something fundamental.

I have a map built with Google My Maps that I would like to work on using the JavaScript API. Amongst other things, I was looking at the examples from [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples), but I did not manage find a "decent" way.

Is it possible to directly read/write from/to My Maps, or is the KML export the only option to work on My Maps data using a custom application?

Comment: what exactly do you want to read/write?

Comment: Markers for the most part, but potentially anything My Maps supports. The thing is that users are already creating data in My Maps and they are missing features.  A browser extension may be another (ugly?) option. Maybe creating a custom application is easier than I'd expect now and I should be doing that using a one time migration export/import.

Comment: I have the same question.  How to access the data from My Maps.  We've been successful at initializing a map to find places and add markers using the Javascript API but to access the data of an existing map created in My Maps that's what we are looking for.